# Get only request/response with loading time >= 1 Sec BrowserMob in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browsermob, browsermob-proxy, har

Is it possible to filter the request/response from .HAR whose loading time is >=1 Sec? I need to save har object into seperate file and upload into har viewer. Below is my code to generate .HAR file.

```
//BrowserMobProxy
        BrowserMobProxy server = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        server.start(0);
        server.setHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.getAllContentCaptureTypes());
        server.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);
        server.newHar("Bhaskar");

        //PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS
        ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<>();
        cliArgsCap.add("--proxy=localhost:"+server.getPort());
        cliArgsCap.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");

        //DesiredCapabilities
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36";
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
        capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", userAgent);
        capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
        capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"D:/req/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");

        //WebDriver
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

        //HAR
        Har har = server.getHar();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\HAR-Information.har");
        har.writeTo(fos);
        server.stop();
        driver.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed the "timings" block in your HAR?

This object describes various phases within request-response round trip. All times are specified in milliseconds.

```
"timings": {
    "blocked": 0,
    "dns": -1,
    "connect": 15,
    "send": 20,
    "wait": 38,
    "receive": 12,
    "ssl": -1,
    "comment": ""
}
```

- blocked [number, optional] - Time spent in a queue waiting for a
  network connection. Use -1 if the timing does not apply to the
  current request.
- dns [number, optional] - DNS resolution time. The time required to
  resolve a host name. Use -1 if the timing does not apply to the
  current request.
- connect [number, optional] - Time required to create TCP connection.
  Use -1 if the timing does not apply to the current request.
- send [number] - Time required to send HTTP request to the server.
- wait [number] - Waiting for a response from the server. receive
  [number] - Time required to read entire response from the server (or
  cache).
- ssl [number, optional] (new in 1.2) - Time required for SSL/TLS
  negotiation. If this field is defined then the time is also included
  in the connect field (to ensure backward compatibility with HAR 1.1).
  Use -1 if the timing does not apply to the current request.
- comment [string, optional] (new in 1.2) - A comment provided by the
  user or the application.

The send, wait and receive timings are not optional and must have non-negative values.

An exporting tool can omit the blocked, dns, connect and ssl, timings on every request if it is unable to provide them. Tools that can provide these timings can set their values to -1 if they don’t apply. For example, connect would be -1 for requests which re-use an existing connection.

The time value for the request must be equal to the sum of the timings supplied in this section (excluding any -1 values).

Following must be true in case there are no -1 values (entry is an object in log.entries) :

> entry.time == entry.timings.blocked + entry.timings.dns +
>       entry.timings.connect + entry.timings.send + entry.timings.wait +
>       entry.timings.receive;

**Once you have the complete HAR object, you can iterate over the HAR and calculate the total item of each element, and remove those who have time >1000ms. Then you can save the HAR object into the file.**